# Date mapper doesn't accept the data sent although it seems to be in an acceptable format

Tags: php, elasticsearch

My request it like this,

```
$params = [
'index' => 'reportings',
'type' => 'datax',
'id' => $row["id"],
'body' => [
'id' => $row["id"],
'dateCreated' => "2020-11-20 20:39:53"
'dateUpdated' => "2020-11-20 20:39:53"
]
];
$response = $client->index($params);
```

and the mapping for these rows are like this,

```
"dateCreated": { "type": "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis" }, "dateUpdated": { "type": "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis" },
```

The error is "mapper [dateCreated] cannot be changed from [date] to [text]"

And when I try to send it as epoch, it recognizes it as long. How can I make it recognize it as date data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to replace the space with T and also change the mapping to `strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis` then I could index all the data!